# How to make Google+ JavaScript tag pass W3C validiation

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus, w3c-validation

I've got Google+ button on my site. It works fine, but W3C validator shows error:

> The text content of element script was not in the required format:
>   Expected space, tab, newline, or slash but found < instead.

Here is the code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>lang:"pl";</script>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: When `src` is specified the script body can only contain whitespace and comments.

Comment: Thanks, I've canceled lang text and it passed their (W3C) test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The W3C validator is complaining about the contents of `<script src...>` tag. According to [these specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#inline-documentation-for-external-scripts), a script tag with `src` attribute can only contain whitespace and/or JavaScript comments.

You can use [the following syntax](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript#configuration_options) instead:

```
<script>
    window.___gcfg = { lang: "pl" };
</script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```